# Is it possible to output and rename build artifacts from the TeamCity checkout directory (that are not archives)?

Tags: teamcity

I have gone through the documentation for TeamCity on build artifact outputs

(https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths)

However, it doesn't seem clear to me as to how I can output a standard file from the build checkout directory, AND rename it when placing it into the build's artifacts.

I can do this pretty easily using archive file designations. For example:

```
%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\TestProject.Installer\DiskImages\*.exe => setup-1.0.%build.counter%.zip
```

However, this would just simply zip up the executable installer file as a zip file with my renamed specification, where I actually just want it to stay as an .exe file. The problem I can see is that this rename convention only works on archive file types according to the above TeamCity linked documentation.

So is it possible to rename an executable file that is fetched from the build checkout directory and place it into the build artifacts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. Add command line step which will rename the artifact

```bash
ren Release\oldname.exe newname_%build.number%.exe
```

2. Define artifact as path to the renamed file.

```bash
newname_%build.number%.exe
```

Comment: and often, using Release\oldname.exe newname_%build.number%.exe is enough.

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible to rename build artifacts using TeamCity. The needed .exe file name should be configured inside your build script.

Comment: Thanks - nice to get confirmation that it is not possible, I was under the impression I would need to use a bit of custom script to handle this if it wasn't possible then.

Comment: It is simply possible, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, as I noted above you can rename artifacts inside the build script. But it's not possible to rename artifacts using TeamCity [Artifacts path](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-PathsPatterns) field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following thing when you are using octopack with msbuild to create the nuget package.

The command line parameter /p:OctoPackAppendToPackageId=foo adds foo to your nuget package name. [Docs](https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/nuget-packages/using-octopack) (under publishing)

**Example:**

Without parameter: abc.nupkg

With parameter: abc.foo.nupkg